# HTML5 range slider values on the go using jQuery (not UI)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using default HTML5 range slider.  It works, but is it possible to change the value of this slider on the go (when mousebutton is clicked on range bar and mouse slides to any side)?
Important: is it possible without using jQueryUI, but with jQuery (or pure JS) only?

**HTML:**

```
<input type="range" name="oc-max-price" id="oc-max-price" min="390" max="5000" step="10" value="5000">
<span id="oc-max-price-val">5000</span>
```

**jQuery code:**

```
$('#oc-max-price').change(function () {
    var mP = $('#oc-max-price').val();
    $('#oc-max-price-val').text(mP);
    console.log(mP);
});
```

Comment: try .on('input', ....

Comment: View the edited answer for pure JS solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `oninput`

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#oc-max-price').on("input", function () {
        var mP = $('#oc-max-price').val();
        $('#oc-max-price-val').text(mP);
        console.log(mP);
    }); 
    });
```

Pure `JavaScript`

```
var input = document.querySelector('#oc-max-price');

var messages = document.querySelector('#oc-max-price-val');

input.addEventListener('input', function()
{
    messages.textContent = input.value;
});
```

Comment: `mousemove` does not trigger iPhone/iPad or any touch device sadly. So i guess `input` is anyway better.

Comment: Is it ok if I use bunch of them (input, touchmove and mousemove)? Or maybe it's "mauvais ton"?

Comment: Just look at the compatibility https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.oninput. I dont think their should be any issue in `firefox` or `IE` as it is fully supported. The issue could be machine configuration/situation dependent.

Answer (score 1):

So, like on `mousemove` & `touchmove`?

```
$('#oc-max-price').on('mousemove touchmove', function () {
    var mP = $(this).val();
    $('#oc-max-price-val').text(mP);
});
```

[**Here's a fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/uhb7xqd6/)

Answer (score 1):

Set an interval: http://jsfiddle.net/2ej2m3kp/

```
 $('#oc-max-price').mousedown(
    setInterval(function () {
        var mP = $('#oc-max-price').val();
        $('#oc-max-price-val').text(mP);
        console.log(mP);
    }, 100));
```